# iPhone text output of NSDictionary key and NSArray strings

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, user-interface, uitextview

I'm new to development, I'm creating a simple dictionary style app for the iPhone for personal use, and I'm stuck now that I've gotten to creating the UI.

My dictionary app stores NSString data for output in an NSDictionary (keys) and NSArrays (NSString lists).

When printing to the console I used `NSLog` to output the NSDictionary keys the NSArrays' strings.

I printed the NSStrings of NSArrays like this:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [randomlySelectedArray subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(0,5) ]);
```

And the keys of he NSDictionary naturally like this:

```
NSLog(@"%@", randomKey);
```

So far I haven't figured out how to replicate this output in the simulator using UI.

I'm thinking that I'll need to use UITextView or UILabel but I'm having trouble making it work.

Does anyone have any pointers?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to take a look at this tutorial from Apple: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/JumpRightIn/iPhone101/Articles/00_Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011343-TP40007514

There's a section on configuring the view and creating outlets to text fields.

Comment: That's exactly the type of resource I was looking for. A thousand thanks!